# Trying to create a pdf file with Kotlin. Getting "java.io.FileNotFoundException: 20210922: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)" error/

Tags: android, kotlin, itext, pdf-generation

Trying to create a pdf file with Kotlin in android studio. Getting "java.io.FileNotFoundException: 20210922: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)" error/

My function is :

```
private fun savePDF() {
    val mDoc = Document()
    val mFileName = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    
    val mFilePath = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS.toString() + "/" + mFileName + ".pdf"

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, FileOutputStream(mFileName))

        mDoc.open()
        val chno1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.chno1)
        val data =  chno1.toString().trim()
        mDoc.addAuthor("XYZ")
        mDoc.add(Paragraph(data))
        mDoc.close()
        Toast.makeText(this, "$mFileName.pdf \n is create to \n$mFilePath",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    catch (e: Exception){
        Toast.makeText(this,""+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when(requestCode)
    {
        STORAGE_CODE -> {
            if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                savePDF()
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the only code where a `EROFS (Read-only file system)` error can occur is the `FileOutputStream(mFileName)` instantiation in

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, FileOutputStream(mFileName))
```

Thus, apparently the current working directory of your application is on a *read-only file system*.

Maybe, though, you actually don't want to create that file in the current working directory but instead at the downloads location used in `mFilePath`. In that case use `mFilePath` instead of `mFileName`, i.e.

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, FileOutputStream(mFilePath))
```